# Spring Boot Jackson date format

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, date-format

I have a problem with Jackson in SpringBoot. My controller returns dates in format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`, but I need `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` (for mwl-calendar in angular which uses date-fns library).

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/slots", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Set<SlotResponse> timeSlots() {
    return slotService.getSlots();
}
```

SlotResponse:

```
@Data
public class SlotResponse {
    private Instant start;
    private Instant end;
}
```

Additional dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I tried:

1. to use `@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")` annotation
2. to use `spring.jackson.date-format=yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ` configuration
3. to create ObjectMapper manually:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"));
    return mapper;
}
```

4. to enable options `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID` and `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE`

But all of this didn't take effect. Everytime I see this result:

```
[{"start":"2023-05-11T16:00:00Z","end":"2023-05-11T17:00:00Z"}]
```

I use Java 17, SpringBoot 2.7.0, Jackson 2.13.3

What is wrong?

Comment: Your mwl-calendar is intolerant. It should just assume the fraction of second is zero when it is not in the string. The format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. According to the standard, the fraction of second is optional.

Comment: @OleV.V., maybe. It uses date-fns library and it says "Incorrect date" if I use `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`. I didn't go deeper in this problem and tried to fix it on backend side.

Answer (score 3):

You can create custom json serializer for Instant type:

```
    public static class InstantSerializer extends StdSerializer<Instant> {

        public InstantSerializer() {
            super(Instant.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(
            @Nullable final Instant value,
            @NonNull final JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
            @NonNull final SerializerProvider serializerProvider
        ) throws IOException {
            if (value != null) {
                final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
                    .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
                    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
                final String text = formatter.format(value);
                jsonGenerator.writeString(text);
            }
        }

    }
```

Then use it on the field that you want to follow the format:

```
    @Data
    public class SlotResponse {

        @JsonSerialize(using = InstantSerializer.class) // Add this
        
        private Instant start;
        @JsonSerialize(using = InstantSerializer.class) // Add this
        private Instant end;
    }
```

In case you want to make this apply for your whole system, you can add the serializer to jackson:

```
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ...
        final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(new InstantSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        ...
        return mapper;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Sorry, cannot reproduce

With (*only*)

- spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.0
- lombok
- (dev tools, spring-boot-starter-test)

, (shortened) "dto":

```
package com.example.soq76225352;

import java.time.Instant;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class SomeResponse {
  private Instant start = Instant.now();
}
```

and:

```java
@RestController
class DemoController {

  @GetMapping(value = "/slots")
  public SomeResponse timeSlots() {
    return new SomeResponse();
  }
}
```

(no other settings, properties, only defaults..)
, we get:

```json
{"start":"2023-05-11T09:08:23.569050400Z"}
```

which looks *very* like the desired format. (??)

---

As soon I add:

```java
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
```

, I get:

```text
2023-05-11 11:03:49.487  WARN 3732 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver :
   Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
     Could not write JSON: Unsupported field: YearOfEra; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
       Unsupported field: YearOfEra (through reference chain: 
         com.example.soq76225352.SomeResponse["start"])
   ]
```

(-> `/error` -> `404`) !?

---

#### Going deeper

- The format `'Z'` refers to a "literal Z"
- Whereas `Z` refers to the "zone offset" (in form `+HHMM`, see [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) + source documentation)
- On the other hand: `X` is the "zone offset" (as described by `Z`) or (literal) `'Z'` in case of "zero offset"/UTC! [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) :)

#### To make it work:

- in all cases (that's strange for the literal case!), we have to:

  - or `@JsonFormat(timezone = "..." //,...`
  - or `spring.jackson.time-zone`

  ... (explicitly) set the "config time zone", see [Set Jackson Timezone for Date deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7556851/592355)

  - additionally we need to ensure (it is by default):    `spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_WITH_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE=true`
    , see [source code(your version)](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/blob/jackson-modules-java8-2.13.5/datetime/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ser/InstantSerializerBase.java#L142-L148)

##### Given (e.g.)

```properties
spring.jackson.time-zone=UTC
```

##### When/Then

- When format is `'Z'`, then we get `"...Z"`
- When format is `Z`, then we get `"...+0000"`
- When format is `X`, then we get (also) `"...Z"`

---

Relevant, but old:

- [How to Use Spring Boot's 'spring.jackson.date-format' Property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43622259/592355)
- [How to set format of string for java.time.Instant using objectMapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45662820/592355)

Relevant, but not deep/exact (milliseconds) enough:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates

Comment: Thanks a lot for the huge amount of useful information